# nextjs tab click reload same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, router

I have a Next.js page `/product`

When I'm on `/product`, and I click `product` on the top banner(navbar)  (to /product), I wanna get refresh page in `/product` page.

how to refresh in the same page ?

For example, in my top navbar
I have three different link router

- home
- Product
- ask

when i'm in `product` page and click product link again
but i want to refresh whole page again.

i have tried this code down below
was not solution for me

```
  <a onClick={()=>router.push('/product')} >product</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried `onClick={() => router.reload()}`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use router.reload() function like this:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={() => router.reload()}>
      Click here to reload
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript function-

```
window.href.reload()
```

this will reload the page. If you're using nextjs/reactjs you can use it with some promises and conditions..
Hope you'll get your answer. If you still facing issue, just lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks

Comment: if i use window method in nextjs, i need to use useEffect that's not what I want...

Comment: Okay then use, Router.reload(window.location.pathname) in this Router is package of NExtJS.. try with this... By the way in reality javascript is core of all JS languages so please don't try to avoid it.... Thanks